# How can I debug my command controller?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have created a command controller and registered it on my scheduler, like:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][] =
        'Blog\\Events\\Command\\UpdateCommandController';
```

I can execute my command with the scheduler; but, if I enter a `var_dump` or `die` in my `UpdateCommandController`, I will not see any change in [TYPO3](https://typo3.org/) backend.

How can debug my command controller.  And, what is the correct way to do this?

Can someone give me a tip?

Here is command controller, which i will to debug:

```
namespace Blog\Events\Command;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController;

class UpdateCommandController extends CommandController
{
    /**
     * Eventsrepository
     *
     * @var \Blog\Events\Domain\Repository\EventsRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $eventsRepository;

    public function updateCommand()
    {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug the controller by calling it from the command line. To do this, you need a backend user `_cli_lowlevel` (with no privileges).

Then you can execute the script `typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh` using php. To execute your command controller, you need to execute a command similar to this:

```
php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase <controller-name>:<action-name>
```

Both `<controller-name>` and `<action-name>` would be `update` in your case. To see all available actions from CommandControllers, execute this command:

```
php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase help
```

Comment: i create the "cli_lower" user and try to call my command like this: php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase update:update , but nothing happens, i do not get the output of "hello world".

Comment: What does `php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase help` print? And have you named the user `_cli_lowlevel`, or "cli_lower"?

Comment: sorry my mistake, i have a spelling bug in username. Now is fine. After i define my interval for schedule Command like "30 2 * * *", should i create a cron job for call "php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh update:update"?

Comment: No, for executing tasks regularly, you should use TYPO3s scheduler. To run it, you need to create a cron job executing `php typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh scheduler`. Also, you need to add another privilege-less user `_cli_scheduler`. The setup check of the scheduler also tells you the exact command to execute, with absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Typo3 extension [Developer Log](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/devlog) for debuging.
Extension create log records in the database and show them in backend module.

Example of use in Extbase PHP code:

```
$arguments = 'any-data-for-log';

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::devlog(
    '[ClassName::functionName]',
    'extension_name',
    1, // severity
    array('arguments' => $arguments) // log data
);
```

This is a better way (for me).

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 9 and above you can log like this:

```
 $this->logger = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\LogManager::class)->getLogger(__CLASS__);
        $logWriter = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\Writer\FileWriter', ['logFile' => 'typo3temp/logs/my_import.log']);
        $this->logger->addWriter(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\LogLevel::INFO, $logWriter);
```

and then

```
$this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
```